# Did Leah have a physical defect in Genesis 29:17?

Tags: genesis, kjv, jacob, nasb

Genesis 29:17 NASB

17 And Leah’s eyes ***were weak***, but Rachel was beautiful of form and [e]face.

In other translations Leah's eyes are said to be tender

Genesis 29:17 KJV

17 Leah was ***tender eyed***; but Rachel was beautiful and well favoured.

But When compared with Rachel who was said to be beautiful and well favoured it seems she lost to Rachel.

Could the weak/tender eyes have referred to a physical defect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name "Leah" (לֵאָ֖ה) means 'weary'. - Genesis 29:17 is a Hebrew pun : The eyes of Weary (לֵאָ֖ה) were weak.

Genesis 29:17 [MT]
"and The eyes of Leah were weak" (וְעֵינֵ֥י לֵאָ֖ה רַכּ֑וֹת)

"Eyinei" (עֵינֵ֥י) = Eyes ;
"Leah" (לֵאָ֖ה) = Weary ;
"Rakhot" (רַכּ֑וֹת) = Weak / Soft.

- Leah also was "the older" (Ha-Gedolah,  הַגְּדֹלָה֙) daughter of Laban. Leah had been serving her family longer than her younger sister Rachel. - Genesis 29:16 [https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8224/jewish/Chapter-29.htm]

The Eyes (of the older sister) "Weary" were tired. - This Hebrew pun is a clever description of Leah used to identify her characteristics as the older, tired daughter. - Age did not cause Leah to have any physical defect. * Consider how God blesses Leah later in verses 31-35.

Comment: "The name "Leah" (לֵאָ֖ה) means 'weary'". Can you please bring evidence to support your theory? And from which Hebrew root is that? I've never heard of a connection between the Hebrew Leah and weary.

Comment: The Meaning of Leah : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leah_(given_name)

Comment: Meaning of Leah : https://biblehub.com/topical/l/leah.htm

Comment: The Hebrew meaning of Leah : https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3847875/jewish/Popular-Jewish-Hebrew-Girl-Names.htm

Comment: That wikipedia reference is very interesting. It connects it with לָאָה which according to wikipedia means "weary". I have never come across such a word in the bible, so I'm guessing this is highly speculative, but thanks for sharing this.

Comment: BDB lists לֵאָ֔ה under the root; לָאָה ... vb. be weary, impatient
 -- 
Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 521). Clarendon Press.